# Gant view for vacation

Tags: 2010, calendar, gantt-view

I want to create a Gant-view showing the vacations for all users. And I have done that but not in the way I want it. Now each user is able to create events for the vacation say 2 events 1.6 - 20.6 and 15.8 - 30.8. These 2 events is shown as 2 rows in the view. I want ONE and only one row for each user regardless if they have 1,5 or 0 events.

Is it possible with Sharepoint 2010 ?

Comment: If you're open to 3rd party software then this may help (disclaimer - its my companies product) http://www.pentalogic.net/sharepoint-products/planner

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Reporting Services integrated with your SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 2):

Each task is a single item. On default they are separated even if they are belong to one user. Probably you must use custom view (Visual Studio).